# Hiding derived class in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to hide derived class from the client in my WCF service.

Example -

```
[DataContract]
public class Base
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class Derived : Base
{         
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Let's say I've operational contract like

```
[OperationalContract]
Base GetData();
```

Implementation of operational contract

```
public Base GetData()
{
    Derived = new Derived {Id = 1, Name = "Foo" };
    return derived;
}
```

The above example doesn't work. If I add [KnownType(typeof(Derived)] in Base class, and add DataContract attribute to Dervied class then everything seems to work fine. But if I do that the client will see the Derived class, that I want to hide. Is it possible to hide Derived class from the client? Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you cast to Base before returning?  Or you could map it to base (make a new Base and copy over the data, either manually or automatically).

Comment: It throws "There was an error while trying to serialize parameter http://tempuri.org/:DerivedResult". The second suggestion is hack that I would like to avoid.

Comment: Technically, if you're separating your data contracts and your entities, allowing you to decouple and also to turn WCF into an implementation detail, this is not only **not** a hack but it is also given to you for free.  You'd be mapping between multiple entity types and one data contract type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll get the behavior you want hacking equivalence using named DataContracts instead of adding the KnownType attribute, like so:

```
[DataContract(Name="Reply")]
public class Base
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual int IntValue { get; set; }

}

[DataContract(Name = "Reply")]
public class Derived : Base
{

    public String StringProperty { get; set; }
}



Derived blah = new Derived { IntValue = 3, StringProperty = "blah" };
public Base SomeOperation()
{
     return blah;
}
```

Does this do what you want?  Also have a look at DataContractSurrogates (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/14/wcf-extensibility-serialization-surrogates.aspx), which is all told a fancy way for WCF to support what zimdanen said - creating a type for your API, and converting your internal type into this API type in a less "hacky" way.

Comment: Wish I could +1 twice, once for each answer. :)